# ajax cannot find my controller and function when i submit ajax form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and the problem is that when i submit this ajax:

```
$("#checkstudnumbutton").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '<?php echo base_url();?>member/Uploadv2/checkAuthor',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {studnum:$("#authorstudentnum").val()},
            success:function(data)
            {
                if(data.exist===true)
                {
                    // populate modal inputs
                    alert('exists');
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("yo");
                    // show div alert
                    $('#alertnostud').show();
                    $('#alertnostud').delay(5000).hide();
                }
            },
            error:function()
            {
                alert('ajax failed');
            }
        });
    });
```

the console shows 500 (internal server error) please help

Comment: `500` mean some issue in the controller, may be the controller. I guess it is able to to discover the controller.

Comment: then you have a problem on the server side, try posting with a `form` or `postman` to see what's the error, or put this in your ajax to see error in the console `error: function(err){console.log(err);}`

Comment: I think you may need quotation marks around `studnum` in your `data`.

Comment: 500 occur becz your member/Uploadv2/checkAuthor file has some error

Comment: When ajax is fire check URL and see whether URL exists or not, as it can be just typo or issue with GET/POST request

Comment: Is the above code placed in a js file? What are you getting when `alert('<?php echo base_url(); ?>')` ?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, "500 Internal Server Error" is thrown when web server (such as Apache or Nginx) encounters "PHP Fatal Error". PHP Fatal Error could be thrown for many reasons; however, most common errors are caused by URL mismatch. Make sure that output value of the URL is valid URL:

```
<?php echo base_url();?>member/Uploadv2/checkAuthor
```

You can check this by viewing the source in the browser.

**Mozilla Firefox**
To view the source code of a web page in Mozilla Firefox, follow the steps below. Open Mozilla Firefox and navigate to the web page of your choice. Press the Alt key to bring up the browser's menu bar. Select Tools, Web Developer, and then Page Source.

**Google Chrome**
To view the source code of a web page in Google Chrome, follow the steps below. Open Chrome and navigate the web page of your choice. Click on Customize and control Google Chrome icon on the upper right-hand side of the browser window. From the drop-down menu that appears, select More tools and then Developer tools.

Also, make sure that the *base_url* is configured correctly in your config file. See the CodeIgniter documentation on [base_url](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#base_url).

Answer (score 0):

500 (internal server error)
 in your controller error
 cannot find controller must error 404
 please throw error

in success scope of ajax
 such as 
 model

```
data.message
```